# Ionic5 vue3 can't add background image to <ion-content>

Tags: css, image, vue.js, ionic-framework

Hi hackers and handsomes:
Follow this article [Ionic full screen background image](https://stackoverflow.co%20m/questions/23906945/ionic-full-screen-background-image) .I guess it is  vue specific bug.

Code:

background_image_sample.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content>
      <h1>background_image_sample Page2</h1>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { IonPage, IonContent } from "@ionic/vue";
import './background_image_sample.css';

export default {
  components: {
    IonPage,
    IonContent,
  },
};
</script>
```

background_image_sample.css

```
ion-content {
  --background: url('./assets/background.png') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat
}
```

cloud env: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-meadow-lyuo0?file=/src/background_image_sample.vue:52-75)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing it to `script` tag you should
put it on style tag

`<style src="./background_image_sample.css"></style>`
or

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 @import "./background_image_sample.css";
</style>
```

Im not so sure regarding on `@import` it might be only for `sass/scss` language

Comment: first thank mr.403 welling to help. Unfortunately I double check suring import css is sucess.
if you have time. invite you to visit code sandbox. you  see current env. i reporduced probleam there. thx!